# load templateUrl within Controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an $routeProvider in my AngularJS which provides a templateUrl and controller,

I was wondering if it is possible to make the temlateUrl within the controller instead.

Reason for this is my code is partially async and this would easen the complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a template defined for a route (AFAIK), but you could have the template be:

```
<div ng-include="actualTemplateUrl"></div>
```

And in the controller set the URL:

```
$scope.actualTemplateUrl = "/path/to/actual/template.html";
```

Comment: can I not use the ng-view instead?

Comment: `ng-view` populates it with the template defined at config-time with `$routeProvider`. Btw, you can have the templateUrl be a function, but if your requirement is that the controller decides on the template - then `ng-include` seems like the right way for me. EDIT: just to clarify - this would be done in addition to `ng-view`

Comment: Sadly its not working for me..
when I try to change the $scope.templateUrl = "test.html"; inside the .then() field, it won't work, but outside it does. Async such a pain..

Comment: works fine for me: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DC9wOweCJ4166JQ3YZAh?p=preview)

Comment: Does timeout count as asynchronous? I only see synchronous code there. Async i'm talking about is the js working with promises and callbacks. But thanks anyways.

Comment: $timeout is async and returns a `.then`-able promise. Go to plunker again to see the change - it works. Post your code to plunker if you're having other issues. For example, is your async code happens outside of the Angular digest loop? if you added `$scope.$apply()`, would that work?